# import error when using Material UI mobile time picker

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to use a material-ui mobile time picker from the new material ui release, but I'm getting a node modules import error I can't figure out.
I tried to recreating the error in stackblitz and codesandbox, no luck.

error message:
./node_modules/@material-ui/core/Paper/Paper.js
Attempted import error: 'integerPropType' is not exported from '@material-ui/utils'.

package.json:

```
    "@emotion/react": "^11.4.0",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.3.0",
    "@material-ui/core": "^5.0.0-alpha.34",
    "@material-ui/lab": "^5.0.0-alpha.34",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "^4.0.3",
```

component code:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import MobileTimePicker  from '@material-ui/lab/MobileTimePicker';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import AdapterDateFns from '@material-ui/lab/AdapterDateFns';
import LocalizationProvider from '@material-ui/lab/LocalizationProvider';

export default function Day() {
 return( 
    <div>
        <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns}>
            <MobileTimePicker
            label="For mobile"
            renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} />}
            />
      
        </LocalizationProvider>
    </div>)
}
```

Not sure if this will be helpful but this is the code sandbox that works, and I don't see any differences between my code locally and this sandbox
[code-sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-mobile-time-picker-s2l3o?file=/src/App.js:89-141)

Comment: What is your node version?
Check your node version with this command. `node -v`

Comment: Oh good call, version 14.16.1

Comment: I created project with `create-react-app`, but it works well.

Comment: Oh, very weird. Not sure what it is then, I'm just going to the older version of material ui because I can't get it to work. Thanks for your help